# Why had EE.SE no 'hardware-software-codesign' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic, off-topic

Regarding this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33574155/3719459) on SO and the follow-up [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309603/3719459) on MSO, I tried to find the `hardware-software-codesign` tag to 'proofe' that this question could be asked on EE.SE.

Why does this tag not exist?

- No need for it?
- Off-topic?
- ...

Comment: That SO question would have lasted for about 3 minutes on EE.SE before it got closed.  It's off-topic on SO, because it's not about software.  It's off-topic on EE.SE, because it's dumb and lazy.

Comment: The SE network has no rules against 'dumb' questions ...

Comment: SE network has guidelines requiring preliminary research.

Comment: @Paebbels: of course it has, we even have low quality queues and delete reasons.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea what you're trying to suggest with such an odd tag.

The question may be on-topic, but it is way too broad to seriously consider. Look at the [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for an indication about what *shouldn't* be asked, and you will find that your example is not a good fit for here or Stack Exchange in general.

Hardware related software questions are generally on-topic.